# Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar?

Tags: gradle

I follow the instructions in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch, but when it says to run:

./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar

the build fails with the above error.

There is message before the failure that says:

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

but everyone online says that's just a warning.

The build doesn't appear to create or download build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar.

Currently completely blocked on first attempt to use Gradle.

Comment: can you provide the output logs when executing  `./gradlew build` ? and is there a /build/libs directory created ?

Comment: When I run:

$ ./gradlew -v

it says:

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/Jim/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-bin/e8p42vx1m7a3mz9ydmjagn6wn/gradle-4.8.1/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()

Comment: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

but then outputs the version. I'm assuming the warnings are just warnings.

Comment: Running the build:

$ ./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar --warning-mode=all
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar

There is a build/libs directory:

$ ls build/libs
demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Environment info:

Git Bash (MINGW64) command line
Visual Studio Code 1.27.2
Gradle 4.8.1
Build time:   2018-06-21 07:53:06 UTC
Revision:     0abdea078047b12df42e7750ccba34d69b516a22
Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          10.0.2 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.2+13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: From your comments it seems that the generated lib is `demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, while you are trying to execute `java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar`   : is there any jar named *gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar* in your built artefacts?

Comment: The config seems to be corrupted. I'll restart the tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem.

The tutorial is in error in what you need to run. It should be

`$ gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar`

I think that they updated the code, but forgot to update the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when build a simple project with Maven on Intellij IDEA. (Ubuntu 18.04.2).

Just typed terminal (in project directory):

```
$ sudo mvn package
$ java -jar ./target/(your-project-name)-(<version> at pom.xml).jar
```

For example my project name is `hello-world-spring` and version name in `pom.xml` is `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`, I have to type:

```
$ sudo mvn package
$ java -jar ./target/hello-world-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Maybe this method can work for gradle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of the jar file `build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar`. For your case, the jar might be in a different folder. If your code is in a module in the main project, then the jar will be in the build folder of the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you git clone the repo, then the tutorial works. If you "To start from scratch, move on to Build with Gradle.", then the tutorial doesn't work. There are missing setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I changed the command to `java -jar target/rest-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` (I checked the .jar file in target folder and found that the file name was incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

Parent folder of my project was having spaces in it's name, i changed it to the underscore and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the command line as it was in the official guide:

```
./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar
```

First, the above command line has two parts:
(1) ./gradlew clean build    //Use gradle wrapper to build
(2) java -jar build/libs/gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar   //To run an application packaged as a JAR file

Now, one might run into issues with one part or both parts. Separating them and running just on thing at a time helped troubleshoot.

(1) didn't work for my Windows, I did the following instead and that built the application successfully.

```
.\gradlew.bat clean build
```

Now moving to (2) java -jar build/libs/gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar
It literally means that "Run a jar file that is called gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar under this directory/path: build/libs/" Again, for Windows, this translates to build\libs\ , and there's one more thing that may catch you: The jar file name can be slightly different depending on how it was actually named by the configuration in initial/setting.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'actuator-service'
```

Note that the official guide changed it from 'gs-actuator-service' to 'actuator-service' in their sample code but hasn't updated the tutorial accordingly. But now you know where the jar file name comes from, that doesn't matter anymore, and you have the choice to rename it however you want.

Having all the factors adjusted, below is what eventually worked in my case:

```
java -jar build\libs\actuator-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or
java -jar C:\MyWorkspace\Spring\gs-actuator-service\initial\build\libs\actuator-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar //with fully qualified path

If you are curious where does "-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" come from, here it is:
in build.gradle

```
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Again, you have the choice to modify it however you want. For example, if I changed it to 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, the command line should be adjusted accordingly

```
java -jar build\libs\actuator-service-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to execute .jar file that doesn't exist. After building the project go to ./build/libs and check the name of freshly built .jar file and then in your project directory run:

```
./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/name-of-your-jar-file.jar
```

or you can set version property to empty string in your build.gradle file
`version = ''`
after that:

```
./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/your-project-name.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, these commands solved the problem: "Error: Unable to access jarfile springboot.jar":

`cd target`
`java -jar springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

run     `./mvnw package`

Now a folder named target is created and you can see a jar file inside it.

then execute `java -jar target/<jarfilename>`